# Tracing a level surface

Tags: c++, math, graphics, calculus

I have C++ code with a continuous scalar function in three variables and I would like to draw a surface that represents where this function is zero.  I've had home success that gives me partial surfaces and I have an idea for starting at a point on the surface and tracing out the rest but I wondered if there is a library that can already do this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [marching cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes). [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) has an implementation. See also [Efficient implementation of marching cubes cases with topological guarantees](http://zeus.mat.puc-rio.br/tomlew/publication_page.php?pubkey=marching_cubes_jgt), which contains a paper and an implementation.